# How to post a comment on Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, comments, privileges

> **Possible Duplicate:** 
>   [How do comments work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work)

Under many questions asked on Stack Overflow people have posted comments. They are not the answers as we can't vote on them, etc. They appear greyed out right below the question. How does a user post such a comment?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/privileges

Answer (score 0):

You need a reputation of at least 50.

https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment

You can find more information on building up your reputation at:

https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/

Answer (score 0):

Once you have a certain reputation you are allowed to comment on people's answers. Reputation is explained in the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation).

Comment: I prefer to read this kind of stuff.Thanks for the post. http://www.essaywritingservices.com